# How many binary strings of length 11 contain five consecutive 0s or five consecutive 1s？

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

The answer is 502 but why?
I use $$(^7C_1\cdot2^6-^6C_1\cdot2^5)\cdot2-2$$
$C(7,1)*2^6$ count 11111 and 00000 as one number

$-C(6,1)*2^5$ more than 6 consecutive 111111 or 000000 count twice(1111111 three times etc.)

11111011111 and 00000100000 count twice

Comment: Welcome to MSE. [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 3):

Let's start with this: a sequence of bits has a $5$-bit streak starting at the $k$th bit if bits $k$ through $k+4$ are all the same and bit $k-1$ either doesn't exist or is different.

So, for an 11-bit number: $2*2^6$ of them will have a streak starting at the $0$th bit, because there are six free bits after the streak; and $6*2*2^5$ of them will have a streak starting at the 1st through 6th bits because committed both before and after there are $5$ free bits.  This gives $512$ ways to do it, but there are a few duplicates, which we'll need to find.

It is possible for two streaks to exist if they start 6 or more bits apart and use the same value, or 5 or more bits apart and use different values.  This gives 0th and 5th with different streaks, 0th and 6th with same or different streaks, and 1st and 6th with different streaks.

```
00000111110
00000111111
11111000000
11111000001
00000100000
00000011111
11111011111
11111100000
10000011111
01111100000
```

There are ten of these and each has been counted twice, so we must subtract $10$ from our initial count, for a total of $502$.